# Different solution for Activity Selection problem with greedy approach

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, greedy

There is a classic solution for famous Activity Selection problem with greedy approach that you can see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/activity-selection-problem-greedy-algo-1/).

But now, I think about another solution. Let's see this sudo code:

```
while(!empty(S))
{
   Select interval I $ \in $ S that overlap least number of other intervals;
   Add I to Result;
   Remove all Interval from S that overlap with I;
}
```

As you can guess S is our input set, I is a member of S and Result is our output set.

If we don't care about time complexity, is this work efficiently and always Result is maximum set? If not, when we don't have efficient output? Is there any example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution doesn't always work. Here is a counter example [image: counter example]